# performing two success handlers on Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a web application which has a lot of ajax requests scattered around all templates

I'm using ajaxSetup on main template, from which all other templates will inherit. In this ajax setup I do some pre and post processing.

```
//on main.html
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr)
    {
        //stuff
    },
    success: function (data)
    {
        //other stuff
    }
})
```

Each ajax request, has a success handler of it's own, which must **also** be performed.

The problem is, that the success handler of the ajax requests will overide  the global one defined in ajaxSetup.

```
//on specific.html
$.ajax({
    success: function (data){
         //request specific request handler which overrides $.ajaxSetup.
    }
})
```

My question is, is there anyway I can work around this replacement? I didn't want to have to write the same code, or function call on each of the individual ajax requests.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ajaxSuccess` to accomplish this http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $(this).ajaxSuccess(function( event, request, settings ) {
          console.log("Global Success")
    });

    $.ajax({method: "GET", url: "/echo/json",success : function(e){
        console.log("Success");
    }});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jpv5P/1/